# what is the use of string.xml and arrays.xml?

Tags: android, xml

Hi now i am download one android sample source but why they are creating string.xml and arrays.xml file (res/value/string.xml and arrays.xml) I dont know what's the use of those xml file please help me....I am new for android application......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files provide a central location for static application-wide data. Separating this data from the main application code could be seen as being beneficial to the overall application structure

Answer (score 0):

These files can be used to [provide resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) to your application. [String resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) you can use to provide styled text or multi-language text. [Array resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) are often used for providing an array of drawable that can be for example used to build an animation.